# saveAsParquetFile fails on both partition and no partition

Tags: apache-spark, ibm-cloud

Your help is much appreciated. The closest bug report I have found is https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-7837. Has anyone else seen this issue? Please let me know if you have seen errors in below stacktrace and know what is wrong.

When I call df.repartition(1).saveAsParquetFile() or df.saveAsParquetFile() fails to save row data in the parquet files and see below stacktrace:

```
Name: org.apache.spark.SparkException
Message: Job aborted.
StackTrace: org.apache.spark.sql.sources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.insert(commands.scala:166)
org.apache.spark.sql.sources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.run(commands.scala:139)
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ExecutedCommand.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:57)
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ExecutedCommand.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:57)
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ExecutedCommand.doExecute(commands.scala:68)
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:88)
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:88)
org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:147)
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:87)
org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(SQLContext.scala:950)
org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$QueryExecution.toRdd(SQLContext.scala:950)
org.apache.spark.sql.sources.ResolvedDataSource$.apply(ddl.scala:336)
org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:144)
org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:135)
org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.saveAsParquetFile(DataFrame.scala:1508)
$line46.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:22)
$line46.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:27)
$line46.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:29)
$line46.$read$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:31)
$line46.$read$$iwC.<init>(<console>:33)
$line46.$read.<init>(<console>:35)
$line46.$read$.<init>(<console>:39)
$line46.$read$.<clinit>(<console>)
java.lang.J9VMInternals.initializeImpl(Native Method)
java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:235)
$line46.$eval$.<init>(<console>:7)
$line46.$eval$.<clinit>(<console>)
java.lang.J9VMInternals.initializeImpl(Native Method)
java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:235)
$line46.$eval.$print(<console>)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:95)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:56)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:620)
org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(SparkIMain.scala:1065)
org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$Request.loadAndRun(SparkIMain.scala:1338)
org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.loadAndRunReq$1(SparkIMain.scala:840)
org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:871)
org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:819)
com.ibm.spark.interpreter.ScalaInterpreter$$anonfun$interpretAddTask$1$$anonfun$    apply$3.apply(ScalaInterpreter.scala:296)
com.ibm.spark.interpreter.ScalaInterpreter$$anonfun$interpretAddTask$1$$anonfun$    apply$3.apply(ScalaInterpreter.scala:291)
com.ibm.spark.global.StreamState$.withStreams(StreamState.scala:80)
com.ibm.spark.interpreter.ScalaInterpreter$$anonfun$interpretAddTask$1.apply(ScalaInterpreter.scala:290)
com.ibm.spark.interpreter.ScalaInterpreter$$anonfun$interpretAddTask$1.apply(ScalaInterpreter.scala:290)
com.ibm.spark.utils.TaskManager$$anonfun$add$2$$anon$1.run(TaskManager.scala:123)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1157)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:627)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:801)
```

Comment: I am getting same error on bluemix spark service. Were you able to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

This problem is resolved in 1.6.0.
IBM Bluemix Service now has Spark 1.6.0.
Please create new service and run notebook the same code in this new instance, that will resolve the issue.

Thanks,
Charles.